# Datatable not displaying the name of the field that is referenced

Tags: apex, aura

The datatable doesn't display the product name(reference a look up field). I already include the product__r.Name in the query in the getStocksController.apxc. Anybody has an idea why?

getStocksController.apxc

```java
public class getStocksController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Stocks__c> getStocks(){
        List<Stocks__c> stockLists = [select Id, Name, Product__c, product__r.Name, Quantity__c 
                                           from Stocks__c];
        return stockLists;
    }
}
```

displayStocks.cmp

```html
<aura:component controller="getStocksController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global"
>
    <aura:attribute type="Stocks__c[]" name="stockList"/>
    <aura:attribute name="mycolumns" type="List"/>
      
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fetchStocks}"/>
      
    <lightning:datatable data="{!v.stockList }"
                         columns="{!v.mycolumns }"
                         keyField="Name"
                         hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
</aura:component>
```

displayStocksController.js

```js
({
    fetchStocks : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.fetchStocksHelper(component, event, helper);
    }
})
```

displayStocksHelper.js

```js
({
    fetchStocksHelper  : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mycolumns', [
            {label: 'Stock Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Product Name', fieldName: 'product__r.Name', type: 'text'},
            {label: 'Quantity', fieldName: 'Quantity__c', type: 'number'},
            ]);
        
        var action = component.get("c.getStocks");
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.stockList", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I've linked an answer that should provide you with the most of what you need to know. However, I see one other problem. JavaScript is case sensitive, so if `Product__c` is the correct case for the field, then `Product__r.Name` will be the proper field name you'll need to map from.